# Javascript Equivalent for Session Variables in VB?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, session, variables

I have some VB code, which I can no longer use (long story). It goes like this:

```
Session.Contents("LetterVariables") = Nothing
```

Is there a javascript equivalent?

Thanks,

Jason.

Comment: You can drop stuff into hidden fields so it makes it into the request...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent, since javascript runs client side, not server side.

You can use cookies for small amounts of data, and with HTML you can use [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). These allow you to share data across pages (on the same domain) using javascript, but unless using [session cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) or coding specifically for it, these will persist beyond a session.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here:

1. Within JavaScript, you'd need to leverage objects to implement state management.  Just google around for "state management javascript" and I'm sure you'll find something helpful.  But keep in mind the life of that session - for example, in ASP.NET the session typically lives on until the the browser window is closed.  But via JavaScript it's only until that page is either closed or refreshed.
2. Use cookies to manage session state, which lives on until the expiration of said cookies (or until user deletes the cookies).
3. Continue to use ASP.NET session state, but access it via AJAX calls.

Comment: I like this but I also like the comment in the post, dont forget about using literal type controls or hidden fields for state.

Comment: True, you could do that.  I didn't mention it because that puts a dependency on the UI - your presentation/view is now being developed with not just UI but also state management in mind.  I (in most cases) prefer a clear separation of concerns (design pattern plug).

Comment: I also didn't want to steal Josh's thunder.  :)